# Avoid the number of select queries that are generated while doing a join fetch

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, join, fetch

I have two tables Department and Employee with one-to-many mapping.
To retrieve the data from tables, I have written the below query.

```
SELECT distinct d FROM Department d join fetch d.Employee e WHERE d.orgId = :OrgId and e.phoneNumber is not null;
```

This query is generating the main query to fetch the data from the parent table and then there are 11221 select queries that are getting executed sequentially.

The number 11221 is the number of records in the employee table that the result of the query should yield. Parent table has 27 records for the input `orgId`

This is causing a performance issue, resulting in a total time of 2 mins for execution.

I know this kind of question has been asked multiple times. 
But I am not getting a definite answer as to what will work.

I tried below query.

```
SELECT distinct d FROM Department d
    LEFT JOIN FETCH Employee e
    ON d.department_Id
    Where e.phoneNum is not null;
```

Still the same issue.

The Query method is as follows.

```
List<Department> findByOrgid(@Param("Orgid") BigDecimal Orgid);
```

The temporary approach that I am taking is, query the department table, split the number of departments in group of 5 and run them in parallel. But is there a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure it is the `Employee`s that are getting loaded by the extra queries and not some associations `Employee`s have to yet another entity? It would be easier if you posted the `Department` and `Employee` entity as well

Comment: Yes. It printed in the log.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097)